# uploading image to apache tomcat server with android

Tags: java, android, apache, tomcat, upload

I want to upload an image to my local apache tomscat server and im looking for a sample code .
please let me know if the server allow or not reciving files and if there any other methods to send images from android to apache tomcat server

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288502/upload-file-on-apache-server

Answer (score 3):

check it ;)

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

public class HttpFileUploader  {

    URL connectURL;
    String params;
    String responseString;
    String fileName;
    byte[] dataToServer;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    HttpFileUploader(String urlString, String params, String fileName) {
        try {
            connectURL = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("URL FORMATION", "MALFORMATED URL");
        }
        this.params = params + "=";
        this.fileName = fileName;

    }



    void doStart(FileInputStream stream) {
        fileInputStream = stream;

        String exsistingFileName = "asdf.png";

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        String Tag = "3rd";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

            Log.e(Tag, "Starting to bad things");
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL
                    .openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                            + exsistingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

            // create a buffer of maximum size

            int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            int maxBufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...

            int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // close streams
            Log.e(Tag, "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            // retrieve the response from server
            int ch;

            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                b.append((char) ch);
            }
            String s = b.toString();
            Log.i("Response", s);
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this piece of code is working in my app, so in Your app, should be working too ;) and dont forget vote, when you wiil be have more than 15 points ;D